# Problem Solved - Multiple issues with Sweave and Knitr

Tags: xetex, texlive, r, sweave, rstudio

Here is the Github link of the files and a short description of the issues:
https://github.com/Euniceisnice/What-is-wrong-with-my-Tex-and-Sweave

I have never managed to compile my Rnw file with Knitr. First it was overfull hbox and now tex capacity.

[image]

1. I found "texmf.cnf" but I did not manage to edit it. This is not a read-only file but the folder is. I tried to change it but it automatically changed it back immediately.
2. There is no big plot in this Rnw.file.
3. Compiling with Sweave does not have problems. But I need Knitr. I just need highlight in the codes in that PDF.
4. I have a structure.tex file and I used `\Sexpr{knit_child('structure.tex')}`.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can we see the generated latex file? In a lot of cases this is due to a programming error. In others it is very large tikz/pgf images. Have you tried compiling with lualatex instead of pdflatex, it uses dynamic memory allocation (as far as I remember).

Comment: you have given almost no information but the fragment of log that you show shows that you are using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  with either lualatex or xelatex, you should use neither of those packages with Unicode TeX.

Comment: Hi. I uploaded files onto my github https://github.com/Euniceisnice/What-is-wrong-with-my-Tex-and-Sweave